# How do I configure Firebug to use Eclipse/Netbeans as editor

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, firebug

I want to use a real IDE for editing javascript files in combination with Firebug. In the 'Add editor' dialog for Firebug I'm allowed to specify executable and arguments. So the question is really how do I open a file in Eclipse/Netbeans from the command line.

Extra points for allowing me to choose between opening a new Eclipse/netbeans instance and reusing an already running one.

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact answer I'm afraid, but this information might help.

[Eclipse Help - Running Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/help21/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm)
[Fireclipse: Debug from FF straight into Eclipse](http://ajaxian.com/archives/fireclipse-debug-from-ff-straight-into-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried this yet but looks interesting [Javascript Debug Toolkit 2.0.0](http://code.google.com/p/jsdt/wiki/newFeatures)

Also I have heard that [aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) is pretty good

Answer (score 0):

Ever though about the other way round? That means to start eclipse, start there a debug session with Firebug included?

If that could be an answer, see the explanation under [Installing the JavaScript degbugger](http://www.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Installing_the_JavaScript_debugger) for the [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/studio). There is an option to install Aptana inside eclipse instead of loading the whole thing.

**Caveat:** I have never tried that, but I use currently Aptana for programming Rails, perhaps I will use that in the near future.